# Utilising Django annotations with F fields to serialize properties

Tags: django, django-orm, django-2.2

I have the following model property:

```
@property
def is_complete(self):
  return datetime.datetime.now() >= datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.ending_time)
```

I was wondering, how could I convert this to an annotation, such that:

```
MyObject.objects.annotate(is_complete=?).filter(is_complete=True)
```

Would be equiavalent and valid?

Comment: Model properties do not work with annotations. This is because properties are within Python and annotations are at a database level. What do you intent on doing with the `MyObject` queryset?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ExpressionWrapper` to combine the date and time, convert the result to python actual datetime object and finally you can make the comparison.

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.utils import timezone

MyCustomObject.objects.annotate(combine_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(F('date') + F('ending_time'), output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(combine_datetime__lte=timezone.now())
```

Docs: [Django 2.2 Query Expression F with anotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

Comment: Hmmm, very close. I think it should be `output_field` insrtead of `outfield` (typo). But when fixing this, I receive the following error: `'>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'ExpressionWrapper'`

Comment: Not sure you have: I'm still receiving `'>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'ExpressionWrapper'`

Comment: I see, `ExpressionWrapper` does not executes first. I moved the comparison to the filter. It should work now.

Comment: It still doesn't work for some reason. No errors, just returns nothing.

Comment: Bceause that is the filter I need.

Comment: But look at the filter expression. that is exactly what you meant. I used that for to make compatible  with django. Is there difference between `2 >= 3` and `3 <= 2`? That is what I did to your expression.

Comment: No, I can see it is wrong. `datetime.datetime.now() >= datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.ending_time)` evaluates to false when the combined datetime is larger than now ... which is what I want. Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import Value
from django.db.models.functions.datetime import TruncDate

MyObject.objects.annotate(is_complete=Value(datetime.datetime.now() >= datetime.datetime.combine(TruncDate('date'),TruncDate('ending_time'))))).filter(is_complete=True)
```

Comment: Although I appreciate the answer, I can see that this will not work on first glance. You can not reference self inside a query on a ViewSet as self references the ViewSet class.

Comment: Hmmmm, seems closer: `combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not Value`

Comment: Tell me if it's okay :)